# Leading zero, assign "string" to "number" with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a simple timer with React and TypeScript, but I am facing a TS issue with types.

My code looks like this:

```
const tokenTTL = 10;
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState<number>(tokenTTL);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState<number>(0);
  const endTime = new Date();

  useEffect(() => {
    let min = minutes;
    let sec = seconds;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + minutes);

      sec--;
      if (sec === -1) {
        sec = 59;
        min--;
      }

      const minute = ("0" + min).slice(-2);
      const second = ("0" + sec).slice(-2);

      setMinutes(minute);
      setSeconds(second);

      if (min === 0 && sec === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        setValid(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <p className="Timer">
        <span className="minutes">{minutes}</span>
        <span className="divider">:</span>
        <span className="seconds">{seconds}</span>
      </p>
    </>
  );
```

Now all looks good but i need to add leading zeros and here comes some Typing issues.
`const minute = ("0" + min).slice(-2);` and  `const second = ("0" + sec).slice(-2);` is creating a `string`. This makes sens as slice is only avalible for strings.
Now I need to assign it to `setMinutes(minute);` and `setSeconds(second);` here i have `number`.
Using `setSeconds(Number(second));` will remove lead zero

Comment: You should use `Intl` instead of trying to format dates and times yourself. And you should add the leading zeroes inside the JSX, not inside your `useEffect` function. Also, I don't think you should be using `setInterval` like that.

Comment: JavaScript `number`s don’t have “leading zeros”; they’re stored as double precision floating point numbers, a form of binary scientific notation.  If you want to display a number in decimal notation with a leading zero you do that in display code only; you don’t try to store the displayed string as a number.

Comment: @jcalz a `number` value is not necessarily internally represented as an IEEE-754 `double`. Most JS engines use a tagged representation for fast integer operations as well as tricks to reduce or mitigate IEEE-754 rounding errors, such as shifting the radix point 2 or 4 places (which is useful when dealing with currency values). Though I'll admit that `Number.MAX_VALUE` is equal to C's `DBL_MAX` (`2^1024`) that is because the JS ECMAScript spec requires it.

Comment: @Dai do you have a source for that?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number says that JS numbers are doubles; I could imagine that engines are allowed to do whatever they want as long as the output is correct, but I don't understand how it would be allowable to "mitigate rounding errors" in some way inconsistent with IEEE-754.  I'd love to hear more about this.

Comment: @jcalz Sure - I used to work on the Chakra JS engine when I was at Microsoft, Chakra is now open-source. The MDN article you linked to is written for the benefit of _users_ of JS and it does make a number of claims that the ECMAScript spec doesn't have, like saying "the type **is** a double-precision" - hang on, I'll find the stuff I need.

Comment: @jcalz After [re-reading through Chakra](https://github.com/chakra-core/ChakraCore) for the first time in 6 years, I admit I was wrong about Chakra having "pre-multiplied" numbers (it could be false-memory syndrome or maybe something discussed in a meeting once). Though the `class JavaScriptNumber` type _is complicated_ w.r.t. its internal representation, see `RuntimeCommon.h` and look for how the `FLOATVAR` and `INT32VAR` macros are used at compile-time to pack values into a normal C++ `int`. I could swear there was more logic around `double` values but I can't find it, hmm.